# List of D7 contrib modules that create and use custom tables with full Views 3 support

Tags: 7, views, hooks, database

I'm trying to understand how to properly use Drupal 7 and Views 3 to retrieve data from a completely customized MySQL table.

There are several tutorials for Views 2 and Drupal 6 ([Scratching The Itch: MyWeather](http://www.stevekarsch.com/2008/11/30/scratching-itch-myweather-views-2) being a great example) but very little for Drupal 7 and Views 3.

I would like to compile a list of Drupal 7 Contributed modules that:

1. Define there own, custom tables.
2. Store data in those tables (no nodes).
3. Query those table using the Views 3 API.

It would be very useful as a developer new to Drupal 7 and Views 3 to see live examples of modules that implement functions like [hook_views_api](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7) and [hook_views_data](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--docs--views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7).

Comment: Maybe you could benefit from reading http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/how-do-i-display-an-external-database-data/3321#3321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maillog](http://drupal.org/project/maillog) is a small module which gives you a good example to learn from.

Comment: This serves as a fantastic example for anyone trying to get a grip on how to incorporate custom MySQL tables with Drupal 7's Views 3 module.  Modules like Data, Table Wizard, etc are useful as well, but they are tools to help migrate data, not necessarily examples.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) & [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) or [Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw) & [Importer](http://drupal.org/project/importer).

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be several questions here.

For a good tutorial series on Views3 go to nodeone.se and views the "Taming the Beast" video series.

Since virtually everything in a Drupal site is stored in the database, Views is a UI for sql queries, and thee are so many modules, it may be difficult to compile a comprehensive list!  I've not seen one listed anywhere, perhaps another answerer has. If you search for views using the relevancy setting at drupal.org/projects/modules you will get a long list of related modules that extend or use views.  Certainly key modules such as rule, panels, some modules in ctools, Organic Groups do.  Modules such as relations and relationships and similar modules do as well.

If you select the tag for hooks from your question tags, you will find a couple links relating to hooks at Drupal. If you look at the code for views you will find examples of implementing and calling hooks.